# Why is JSON data from local path shows incorrectly in the UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to parse JSON data from a local file that is available in the project and then populate these data to UITableView.

**My Requirements**

1. parse the json data from local path not from URL
2. Populate the json data to UITableView

**Facing problems**

1. Unable to display the parsed data, ( bracket is displaying in the table view.
2. I am able to print the data in console using dump() but unable to print data in tableView

Updated view controller for passing data to another controller.

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return lookArrayModel.count
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cells = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

            let displayData = lookArrayModel[indexPath.row]

 cells.textLabel?.text = String(describing: displayData.Lookname!)
            cells.detailTextLabel?.text = String(describing: displayData.Lookdetails!)

          //  print(displayData.shadeModel)
             return cells
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


            print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

            // Get Cell Label

            let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
            let currentCell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

             lookNameValue = currentCell?.textLabel?.text

            lookDetailValue = currentCell?.detailTextLabel?.text
       }
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            //let lookShade = LookModelData()
            if (segue.identifier == "segueToLook") {

  let destController:DetailsViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController

              //Set the selecte row index value
                destController.LabelText = String(describing: lookNameValue)
                destController.DetailText = String(describing: lookDetailValue)

              //  destController.arrayData = lookShade.shadeModel as! NSMutableArray

            }
        }
    }
```

Destination view controller. Swift

```
class DetailsViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

            var lookArrayModel = [LookModelData]()
            var arrayData: NSMutableArray = []

            @IBOutlet weak var secondView: UITableView!
            var LabelText = String()
            var DetailText = String()
            var shadeText = String()
            @IBOutlet weak var LookLabel: UILabel!
            @IBOutlet weak var LookName: UILabel!


            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
                print(arrayData)

                LookName?.text = LabelText

                LookLabel?.text = DetailText

               secondView.dataSource = self
                secondView.delegate = self
                secondView.reloadData()
            }
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

                return arrayData.count

            }
            func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

                return 1
            }
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cells = secondView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath)


                let displayData = arrayData

            //    cells.textLabel?.text = String(describing: (displayData as AnyObject))
              //    print(arrayData)


                return cells
            }  

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my code :

Changed lookArrayModel type `NSMutableArray` to `[LookModelData]`. Like those I did some changes. Please check.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
     var lookArrayModel = [LookModelData]()

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let Path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ColorShade", ofType: "json") else { return }

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Path)

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)

            myTableView.dataSource = self
            myTableView.delegate = self

            //Calling the function for adding look
            createLooks(dictionary: json as! NSArray)
            myTableView.reloadData()
        }  catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func createLooks(dictionary:NSArray) {
        for item in dictionary {
            let item1 = item as! NSDictionary
            let lookModal = LookModelData()
            lookModal.Lookname = item1.value(forKey: "Lookname") as? String
            lookModal.LookId = item1.value(forKey: "LookId") as? String
            lookModal.Lookdetails = item1.value(forKey: "Lookdetails") as? String
            lookModal.shadeModel = createshade(shades: item1.value(forKey: "shades") as! NSArray)
            lookArrayModel.append(lookModal)
        }
    }

    func createshade(shades: NSArray) -> [ShadeDescription] {
        var arrayShade = [ShadeDescription]()
        for item in shades
        {
            let item1 = item as! NSDictionary
            let shadeModal = ShadeDescription()
            shadeModal.comboID = item1.value(forKey: "comboID") as? String
            shadeModal.shadeName = item1.value(forKey: "shadeName") as? String
            shadeModal.ShadeType = item1.value(forKey: "ShadeType") as? String
            shadeModal.ShadeCode = item1.value(forKey: "shadeCode") as? String
            arrayShade.append(shadeModal)
        }
        return arrayShade
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lookArrayModel.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cells = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let displayData = lookArrayModel[indexPath.row]

        // You will get like this 
        // print(displayData.LookId!)
        // print(displayData.Lookname!)
        // print(displayData.Lookdetails!)
        // print(displayData.shadeModel!)
        // This is the way to get shade model data
        if let shadeModels = displayData.shadeModel {
            for var shadeModel in shadeModels {
                print(shadeModel.comboID)
                print(shadeModel.ShadeType)
                print(shadeModel.shadeName)
                print(shadeModel.ShadeCode)
            }
        }
        cells.textLabel?.text = String(describing: displayData.Lookname!)

        return cells
    } 
}

class LookModelData
{
    var Lookname:String?
    var LookId:String?
    var Lookdetails:String?
    //Shades Array
    var shadeModel : [ShadeDescription]?
}

class ShadeDescription {
    var ShadeType:String?
    var shadeName:String?
    var comboID:String?
    var ShadeCode:String?
}
```